# Spring Web - two sequential HTTP requests in AsyncHandlerInterceptor while HTTP 500?

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

I  have this `AsyncHandlerInterceptor` in my Spring app (simplified version for question) to log all HTTP requests into DB.

```
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor implements AsyncHandlerInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {

    // Logging HTTP request into database here...

  }

}
```

Activating interceptor in `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation:

```
@Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).order(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
}
```

It works as I expect, but when target controller throws an exception (HTTP 500), interceptor logs two requests instead of one. The first one is HTTP `200 OK` and second (that goes immediately after the first one) logs correctly HTTP `500 Internal Server Error`. I would like to avoid the first one.

**Q: Is there any application reason why interceptors logs two requests or do I have wrong configuration?**

Comment: Maybe one of these requests is the OPTIONS method. Could you try with *curl -v* to obtain a verbose log and compare the success and error traces?

Comment: Both are POST, copies with same query strin etc.